# google place services crashes on calling PlacePicker api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, google-places-api, gmsplacepicker

I am using following code to launch place picker API.

```
      try {

          PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

          startActivityForResult(builder.build(getActivity()), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);

          } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {

          } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {

          }

  manifest.xml 

  <meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
  android:value="@string/places_api_key"/>
```

Device: coolpad Y91-100
    Android version: 6.0.1
    I have also filed a issue in aosp project. Issue number: 228328
    I am getting same crash even if i try to run google placepicker sample app from github project. Link to its github project 
    https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places

```
Following are the crash logs:



    Process: com.google.android.gms.ui, PID: 19319
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.places.ui.placepicker.PlacePickerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void maps.ad.y.o()' on a null object reference
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void maps.ad.y.o()' on a null object reference
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at maps.ad.R.b(Unknown Source)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at xx.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:73)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at tsc.b(:com.google.android.gms:233)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at tps.a(:com.google.android.gms:124)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at oau.b(:com.google.android.gms:340)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at oaq.a(:com.google.android.gms:143)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.a(:com.google.android.gms:7332)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at almv.onResume(:com.google.android.gms:92)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.google.android.chimera.FragmentProxy.onResume(:com.google.android.gms:432)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at gm.a(:com.google.android.gms:12120)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at gm.a(:com.google.android.gms:1286)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at gm.a(:com.google.android.gms:1268)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at gm.p(:com.google.android.gms:2153)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at gm.a(:com.google.android.gms:12126)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at gm.a(:com.google.android.gms:1286)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at gm.a(:com.google.android.gms:1268)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at gm.p(:com.google.android.gms:2153)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at gc.onResumeFragments(:com.google.android.gms:11223)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.google.android.chimera.container.ActivityProxy.superOnResumeFragments(:com.google.android.gms:2418)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.google.android.chimera.Activity.onResumeFragments(:com.google.android.gms:372)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.google.android.chimera.Activity.publicOnResumeFragments(:com.google.android.gms:377)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.google.android.chimera.container.ActivityProxy.onResumeFragments(:com.google.android.gms:471)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at gc.onPostResume(:com.google.android.gms:511)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.google.android.chimera.container.ActivityProxy.superOnPostResume(:com.google.android.gms:2413)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.google.android.chimera.Activity.onPostResume(:com.google.android.gms:363)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.google.android.chimera.appcompat.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume(:com.google.android.gms:183)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.google.android.chimera.Activity.publicOnPostResume(:com.google.android.gms:368)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.google.android.chimera.container.ActivityProxy.onPostResume(:com.google.android.gms:462)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6385)
      11-21 20:02:00.255 19319 19319 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3092)
```

Comment: You may check this [related forum](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10243) which suggested to use Google maps API to get the maps. Then use places autocomplete api to get the search bar. [`android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9071) also fixed the problem.

Comment: @abielita Thanks for the comment. I have already tried hardwareAccelerated = true. It didn't help. If I use the map and autocomplete separately, it will beat the purpose of using placepicker in the first place.